# Using xpathapply to take only the first h2 node of each row in vector of webscrapes

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, sapply

I am trying to parse a (large) vector of scraped html, more specifically the , but some of the pages in the vector have two  in them so the replacement ends up with more rows than the data.  My question: how do I take only the first //h2 in every obs?

This is the code that I tried:

```
data$header = unlist(xpathSApply(htmlParse(data$html, asText=TRUE), '(//h2)[1]', xmlValue))
```

this gave me only the very first.  This code gave me all h2s:

```
data$header = xpathApply(htmlParse(philly$html, asText=TRUE), '//descendant::h2[1]', xmlValue)
```

Any help is appreciated

sample with two:

```
<div id="tutors">

 <h1>Tutors</h1>
<div class="tutor">
<h2>John</h2>
 <p>...</p>
```

```
<div class="tutor">
<h2>Mary</h2>
<p>...</p>
</div>

<div class="tutor">
<h2>David</h2>
<p>...</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

solved it by including the whole root path:

```
data$header = unlist(xpathApply(htmlParse(data$html, asText=TRUE), '/html/body/h2', xmlValue))
```